# Stata. How to order variables in a customized order?

Tags: stata

I have the following:

```
state income stateID race year education
 IL     200    12     2    12    15
 ML     230    32     12    2    10
 ....................................
```

Is there any way to switch variables' spots, so that it appears like:

```
state stateID  year  income  race  education
  IL     12    12     200     2     15
  ML     32    2      230     12    10
 ....................................
```

NOT `order _all`. I do not need alphabetical ordering, I need customized ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `order state stateID  year  income  race  education`?